# convert one column data to two column data in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I achieve this in excel:
[image]

I have a very long list that I want to do the same on that list. Is there any quick way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In column A is your list then in B1 put the formula and drag it down.

```
 =INDEX(A:A,(ROW(A1)-0.5)*2)
```

In C1 put the below and drag it down

```
=INDEX(A:A,(ROW(A2)-1)*2)
```

Your list will get populated as desired.

[image]

Comment: can you make the formula movable to other columns ? (a relative formula I mean)

Comment: Are you referring to your data being in Column I and split in L & M? The same formula shall work in L & M as well, you will have to just change the column reference to I:I instead of A:A